# Java looping 3 times before giving correct output

Tags: java, loops

I'm making an application that quizzes you on politics or astronomy.

My problem is that when you say "politics" or you say "astronomy", it will ask you again 2 more times for your input, before giving the desired output of "test".

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        do {
            if (getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase("neither")) {
                System.out.println("Please enter \'astronomy\' or \'politics\'.");
            }
        getAnswer();
        }
        while(getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase("neither"));
    System.out.println("test");
    }
    public static String getAnswer() {
        Scanner quizType = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Would you like to be quizzed on politics or astronomy?");
        String typeAnswer = quizType.next();
        if (typeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("politics")) {
            return "politics";
        }
        else if (typeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("astronomy")) {
            return "astronomy";
        }
        else {
            return "neither";
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There **no need to** `getAnswer()` 3 times, just `getAnswer()` into a `String` variable and you are good to go.

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answer = "";
        do {
            answer = getAnswer();
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("neither")) {
                System.out.println("Please enter \'astronomy\' or \'politics\'.");
            }
        } while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("neither"));
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    public static String getAnswer() {
        Scanner quizType = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Would you like to be quizzed on politics or astronomy?");
        String typeAnswer = quizType.next();
        if (typeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("politics")) {
            return "politics";
        } else if (typeAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("astronomy")) {
            return "astronomy";
        } else {
            return "neither";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! By the way, do you know if this is a good playlist for learning Java:

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsyeobzWxl7oZ-fxDYkOToURHhMuWD1BK

Answer (score 1):

If you're learning do-while, then you only need to prompt inside your do. Currently you're calling `getAnswer` three times, which forces the repeated prompt.

Here is a quick way to solve it using do-while

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> validAnswers = Arrays.asList("neither","politics","astronomy");
    String answer;

    do {
        answer = promptForAnswer();
    } while(!validAnswers.contains(answer));

    System.out.println("test");
}

public static String promptForAnswer() {
    System.out.println("Would you like to be quizzed on politics or astronomy?");

    return new Scanner(System.in).next();
}
```

Or you can go with the while loop...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> validAnswers = Arrays.asList("neither","politics","astronomy");

    while(!validAnswers.contains(promptForAnswer())) {
        System.out.println("That was not a valid response, try again!");
    }

    System.out.println("test");
}

public static String promptForAnswer() {
    System.out.println("Would you like to be quizzed on politics or astronomy?");

    return new Scanner(System.in).next();
}
```